# Como remover o elemento pai e todo seu conteúdo quando elemento filho for clicado?

Tags: javascript

Nessa marcação, como eu poderia remover o elemento `<li>` (pai) sempre que o elemento `<a>` (filho) for clicado? Lembrando que quero fazer isso sem jQuery.

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <a href="#">example</a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="#">example</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

Tens de juntar um oscultador de eventos nesses elementos `a` e depois usar o `.parentNode` para saber qual é o elemento `li` que procuras.

Vais ter ainda de chamar o `.parentNode` desse `li` pois a API do javascript precisa de saber o pai e filho: [`elementoPai.removeChild(filho);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.removeChild).

Ou seja:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a'); 
for (var i = 0; i<links.length; i++){
    links[i].addEventListener('click', removerPai);
}

function removerPai(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var li = this.parentNode;
    li.parentNode.removeChild(li);
}
```

### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kxpwuLem/

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a'); 
for (var i = 0; i<links.length; i++){
    links[i].addEventListener('click', removerPai);
}

function removerPai(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var li = this.parentNode;
    li.parentNode.removeChild(li);
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li>
      <a href="#">example</a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="#">example</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```